# Setar senha de pareamento?

Tags: android, arduino, bluetooth

Boa tarde, Estou fazendo um aplicação android para se conectar e comunicar com uma arduino via Bluetooth, meu problema é em relação ao pareamento, onde não consigo setar a senha automaticamente para parear com o arduino, mas ele pede a senha para o usuário digitar, ignorando o código feito.

Este é o código, em java, que estou tentando usar, se tiverem algum conselho vai me ajudar muito. Obrigado.

```
if (broadcastActive){
            /* pesquisa remota */
            publishPair("ACTION_PAIRING_REQUEST","pareamento");
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            String name = "";
            try{
                name = device.getName().trim().toUpperCase();
            }catch (Exception e){ }
            publishPair("ACTION_PAIRING_REQUEST","Name: " + name);

            /* alguns aparelhos podem não possuir nome e, por enquanto, devem ser ingnorados */
            if (!name.equals("")) {
                publishPair("ACTION_PAIRING_REQUEST","Name: " + name);

                int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED);
                publishPair("Permission", ""+permissionCheck);
                try {
                    publishPair("ACTION_PAIRING_REQUEST","Vai setar a senha");
                    int defaltPin    = Integer.parseInt(DEFAULT_PIN);
                    int pin          = intent.getIntExtra("android.bluetooth.device.extra.PAIRING_KEY", defaltPin);
                    byte[] pinBytes;
                    pinBytes         = ("" + pin).getBytes("UTF-8");
                    if(device.setPin(pinBytes)){
                        publishPair("device.setPin(pinBytes)", "sucesso");
                    }else{
                        publishPair("device.setPin(pinBytes)", "Falha");
                    }

                    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                        BluetoothDevice dev = null;
                        try{
                            Thread.currentThread().sleep(3000); // 2 segundos
                            dev = listaDePareamento(device.getName());
                        }catch (Exception e){ }
                        if (dev == null) {
                            publishPair("ACTION_PAIRING_REQUEST","O pareamento falhou 1");
                            Toast.makeText(context, "O pareamento falhou 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }else {
                            publishPair("ACTION_PAIRING_REQUEST", "Pareamento realizado com sucesso");
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Pareamento realizado com sucesso", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            broadcastActive = false;
                        }
                    }else{
                        if(device.setPairingConfirmation(true)){
                            publishPair("ACTION_PAIRING_REQUEST","Pareamento realizado com sucesso");
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Pareamento realizado com sucesso", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            broadcastActive = false;
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    publishPair("ACTION_PAIRING_REQUEST","O pareamento falhou: "+ex.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }else{
            publishPair("statu", "broadcastActive é falso");
        }
```